# Dynamic Grouping in VBA

Tags: excel

I am inquiring additional help to alter a report. I am fairly new to VBA and have written the below code in Excel 2010. Quick background - data is being gathered in SQL, and then generated by a proprietary software to excel. I am looking to group dynamic data sets by highlighting the outside borders. The data set will always start at B4, which I have defined below. Essentially, I created this script to highlight a grouping anytime there is a "GroupSummary" value in column B. The grouping ends in the last row anytime there is a value of "2", followed by a value of "0". In the example below, the grouping would end at Row 3.

For example:

```
ROW 1 "Group Summary" , "A" , "0"
ROW 2 "Summary" ,       "A" , "2"
ROW 3 "Summary" ,       "A" , "2"
ROW 4 "Summary" ,       "B" , "0"
```

I now want to take this a step further and highlight the grouping only when the above conditions are met and all the values in the column before last are identical. See example below. The grouping should end at row 3.

```
ROW 1 "Group Summary" , "A" , "0"
ROW 2 "Summary" ,       "A" , "2"
ROW 3 "Summary" ,       "A" , "2"
ROW 4 "Summary" ,       "B" , "2"
ROW 5 "Summary" ,       "B" , "0"
```

Here is the code that I have already wrote:

```
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim Z As Integer, StartRow As Integer, EndRow As Integer
LastCol = Range("B4").End(xlToRight).Column
Z = 5
Do

     If Cells(Z, LastCol) = 0 And StartRow <> 0 Then
        EndRow = Z - 1
        Range(Cells(StartRow, 2), Cells(EndRow, LastCol - 2)).Select
        With Selection
                .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
                .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).ColorIndex = 1
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlMedium
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).ColorIndex = 1
                .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium
                .Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 1
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).ColorIndex = 1
        End With
        StartRow = 0
    End If

    If Cells(Z, 2) = "GroupSummary" Then
        StartRow = Z

    End If

    Z = Z + 1

  Loop Until Cells(Z, 2) = "" And Cells(Z - 1, 2) = ""
```

Comment: Does this code work for you?

Comment: Yes, but now I would like to take it a step further as I mentioned and was wondering if someone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below produces the following output - for you to tweak no doubt (the shaded groups are your data examples):

[image]

**The code:** keeping your basic approach

```
Sub grps()
Dim FirstCol As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim grpRows As Long, grpHere As Long
Dim Z As Long, StartRow As Long, EndRow As Long, gsRow As Long
Dim grpChar As String

FirstCol = 2    'col B
StartRow = 4
EndRow = Cells(Rows.Count, FirstCol).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Cells(StartRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For Z = StartRow To EndRow

        If Cells(Z, FirstCol) = "Group Summary" Then
            gsRow = Z
            grpRows = 1

            With Cells(gsRow, FirstCol)
                grpChar = .Offset(0, 1)
                grpHere = gsRow

                Do Until .Offset(grpRows, 2) = 0
                    If .Offset(grpRows, 1) = grpChar Then
                        grpHere = gsRow + grpRows
                        grpRows = grpRows + 1
                    Else
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop

                If grpRows > 1 Then
                    Range(Cells(gsRow, FirstCol), Cells(grpHere, FirstCol + 1)).Select
                    With Selection
                        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
                        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).ColorIndex = 1
                        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlMedium
                        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).ColorIndex = 1
                        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium
                        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 1
                        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
                        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).ColorIndex = 1
                    End With

                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next Z

End Sub
```

Comment: I used your code instead of mine and it didn't highlight the grouping, so I decided to run the debugger. When I hover over the startrow, it's value stays at 4. Doesn't seem that the code is working its way down the data set. Should I throw a loop in at the end of the code? Similar to the loop I included?

Comment: Hi @user3746034 - the code works for me.  StartRow will always be 4, its Z and grpRows that is doing the iterating.  Open up the Locals window which may be easier to see the variables changing.

Comment: OK I was using "Group Summary" not "GroupSummary". The column that has the values of 0 & 2 is column Y and the identical values are in column X. What should I change in your code so it looks for those columns? As of now, the code is using column C for the identical values.

Comment: Great, well done for adjusting it.  Now, to change the column of the 'identical values' change 'grpChar = .Offset(0, 1)' TO 'grpChar = .Offset(0,22)' i.e. column X is 22 columns offset from FirstCol.  To change the column of 0 & 2s, change 'Do Until .Offset(grpRows,2) = 0' TO 'Do Until .Offset(grpRows,23) = 0'  using the same logic.  Maybe create these offsets as variables  for greater flexibility, if they are likely to change again?  If you want the new columns to have a border then you will need to make appropriate mods.  If so, have a go, and if it doesn't work just come back to me.

Comment: This worked. I also changed If .Offset(grpRows, 1) to If .Offset(grpRows, 22). Thanks for your help barryleajo